# ConnMan running from within the source code repository

Tags: embedded-linux, connman

I have just cloned the ConnMan repo from http://git.kernel.org/cgit/network/connman/connman.git/ and followed the instructions from the **HACKING** text file. Basically I've issued the following commands:

```
# ./bootstrap-configure
# make
```

According to the text file aforementioned, this should be enough to start the daemon by running:

```
# sudo ./src/connmand -n
```

but the following error occurs:

```
Connection ":1.72" is not allowed to own the service "net.connman" due to security policies in the configuration file
```

I've looked into the configuration file under src/main.conf, but does not contain anything relevant for this.
Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the D-Bus policy file from src/connman-dbus.conf to /etc/dbus-1/system.d so that D-Bus can grant the ownership of net.connman when started as root. A 'make install' installs the policy file, but that was not run in this case.

Comment: It should be noted, that `connman-polkit.conf` should also be copied to resolve some issued on desktop linux.